# Vibration analysis scilab

Tags: matlab, analysis, scilab, vibration, waterfall

I have a problem to do a vibration analysis on scilab.
to explain, I have to make a vibration analysis of an engine in 2d and then in 3D (see pictures)

[3d graph I want to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzwPB.png)

[the 2d graph obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAfp8.png)

My basic file consists of a CVS with two columns, with time and acceleration. I used the fft function for the 2D graph, but for the 3D I don't know how to do it.
The code for the 2D graph:

```
sample_rate=1/(Time(2)-Time(1));
N=max(size(Time));
freqfftDatas =[sample_rate*(0:(N/2))/N]';
FFT=fft(Datas(1:N));
n=max(size(freqfftDatas));
fftDatas =abs(FFT(1:n))*2/N;

plot(freqfftDatas, fftDatas);
```

I've read about waterfall, but I don't know how to relate it to my case.

If there are people familiar with scilab who could help me, I thank you!

Comment: Please change your user name otherwise I wont give any further answer to you questions...

Comment: Why the `matlab` tag?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the 

CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know how 

to delete your post, take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of representation you have to use `surf`, here is an example with the sliding window FFT of a chirp like signal:

```
[t,u]=meshgrid(0:0.01:10,0:0.01:1);
y=sin((%pi*(t+u)).^2);
Y=fft(y,1,1);
clf
gcf().color_map=parulacolormap(128);
surf(abs(Y),"facecolor","interp")
gce().color_mode=-1
```

[image]